# Passing vectors by reference to a template method

Tags: c++, python, cython

Been breaking my head trying to pass vectors by reference to a C++ template method but all I get back is an empty list, apparently the parameter is being passed by value.

I am using Cython 0.18 & Python 2.7

Any ideas?

**C++ side**

```
class VectByRef
{ 
public:
  VectByRef::VectByRef();

  template<typename T>
  void GetVector(T& var);
}

template<typename T>
void VectByRef::GetVector(T& var)
{
  var.push_back(1);
  var.push_back(2);
  var.push_back(3);
}
```

**Cython side**

```
cdef extern from "VectByRef.h":
  cdef cppclass VectByRef:
    VectByRef() except
    vector[cython.int] GetVector(vector[cython.int])

def getVector(self):
  cdef vector[cython.int] resultVectInt
  self._vectByRef.GetVector(<vector[cython.int]> resultVectInt)
  print(resultVectInt)  # The result is an empty list []
```

Comment: With the `GetVector` method, why are you defining it as a method of `T`, instead of as a method of `VectByRef` (which it was declared as)?

Comment: I also have this question. I see that you have posted this on other sites. Have you got any answers on a different site?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this actually answers the question, but I can't comment yet to get clarification.

When I tried to compile this I got an error:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘VectByRef::GetVector(std::vector<int>)’`

The error was resolved by changing the call on the Cython side to

```python
.GetVector(<vector[cython.int]&> resultVectInt)
```

removing the type qualification altogether also worked:

```python
.GetVector(resultVectInt)
```

Both of these gave the desired result as well: `[1, 2, 3]`

This was also using Python 2.7, with both Cython 0.17 & 0.19. So I'm guessing either something else is going on, or there's a specific bug with 0.18.